# Android Application - Developing a Wifi File Transfer

Tags: java, android, wifi

I wanted to develop an Android application which allows users to transfer files from an android device to a computer using a WiFi connection. Basically a simplified application of this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&hl=en

The application transfers file using the web browser as the interface. File is being transferred to the computer by downloading. I need to find a way to somehow broadcast a webpage coming from an android device. Any Idea on how to implement this? I know how to create simple applications on android. I managed to create an application which uses an internal database. But pretty much that's all I know in android. We haven't really tried out application which uses wireless connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically need to do is implementing a tiny http server on your android that will serve the page. The UI will display the ip of the android and the port used by the webserver. 
That's all.

I believe this can be achieved within a week end if you just concentrate on get requests.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to look up on this one. Your answer makes sense to me.

Comment: find a library to implement your server, I am pretty sure some http servers work for Android.

Comment: You can use mockwebserver. It is designed for testing but works well and can be used to serve files.

Comment: But how can I determine among the connected devices which of them support file transfer?